# OpenProject Incoming mail issues

Tags: redmine, openproject

I'm trying to create new issues from incoming mail. The problem is that it works with users who have an account, but it does not create work packages from users not in the system. Here is the command:

openproject run bundle exec rake redmine:email:receive_imap host='outlook.office365.com' username='Redacted' password='Redacted' port=993 ssl=true allow_override=type,project project=pending unknown_user=accept no_permission_check=1

I thought that unknown_user=accept and no_permission would do the trick but no such luck. I'm also seeing this in the log:
ERROR -- : Message 27 resulted in error Message was not successfully handled. Message was not successfully handled.

Answer (score 0):

You should navigate to **settings** -> **Authentication** then on **self-registration** dropdown make it **Automatic account creation** and repeat your tests.

[image]

Comment: is it supposed to move processed messages to some folder? Which tutorial are you following?

Comment: https://www.openproject.org/docs/installation-and-operations/configuration/incoming-emails/

Comment: What happens if you change to unknown_user=create ?

Comment: no already checked unknown_user=create syntex but no louk....

Answer (score 0):

Title email require It's enough unknown_user=accept no_permission_check=1